QGIS how to construct a declination diagram
I want to construct a proper declination diagram for my map showing the angles between grid north, magnetic north, and true north and am unsure how to accomplish this.
Edit: I am interested in doing this programmatically based on the centre point of the map extent displayed. I will be creating multiple maps and would like them all to have the same format so my layout will likely be saved as a template that I can then put the map of my target region in.

By the looks of your other question, you are already in Layouts, where I assume you have seen you can place "north arrows" with rotation offsets and thus display 2 or 3 arrows upon your needs. Isn't your other question the key one (compute the map grid declination) ?

Sort of. The north arrows in the Layouts section seem to be limited to simple compass rose SVGs, the link you had in your comment before editing it was more in line with what I was looking for. I'd like to do it all in QGIS if possible but wouldn't be opposed to using that link to generate an SVG to import.

You can use the NCEI (NGDC) online service to determine magnetic declination. They have an API. First get the key here.
Once you have the key, you can use the following code (scroll down) to get magnetic declination (adapt it to your needs). You will probably need to create a custom function in QGIS. Here is the documentation about it.
You can use the following function to determine the center of the map and pass it to NCEI service (latitude and longitude must be in the WGS 84 projection):
@map_extent_center The point feature at the center of the map
geom_to_wkt(
            transform(@map_extent_center, 
                      @project_crs,  
                      'EPSG:4326'
                      ) 
           )


Once the magnetic declination value has been obtained, the rotation function for each of the arrows must be set.

import requests
import datetime
import pprint


def getDeclination(lat, lon, date=datetime.datetime.now(), model='WMM', result_format='json',
                   base_url=r'https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web/calculators/calculateDeclination', key='INSETR_YOUR_KEY_HERE'):
    """
    For more info see https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/calculators/help/declinationHelp.html

    :param lat: decimal degrees or degrees minutes seconds: -90.0 to 90.0
    :param lon: decimal degrees or degrees minutes seconds: -180.0 to 180.0
    :param date: Date in datetime.datetime() format
    :param model: which magnetic reference model to use: 'WMM' or 'IGRF'
                  For 'EMM' use base url: https://emmcalc.geomag.info with paramater magneticComponent=d
    :param result_format: format of calculation results: 'html', 'csv', 'xml', 'json'
    :param base_url:
    :param key: API access key. Get it here: https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/CalcSurvey.shtml
    :return:
    """
    args = [f'lat1={lat}',
            f'lon1={lon}',
            f'model={model}',
            f'startYear={date.year}',
            f'startMonth={date.month}',
            f'startDay={date.day}',
            f'resultFormat={result_format}',
            f'key={key}']

    request_url = base_url + '?' + '&'.join(args)
    r = requests.get(request_url)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return r.json()
    else:
        r.raise_for_status()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # example of use:
    results = getDeclination(lat=61,
                             lon=69,
                             date=datetime.datetime.now())

    print('\nThe results of the query are as follows:')
    pprint.pprint(results)


